# optimize SQL query in 50W-100W table

Tags: mysql

I get this query:

```
SELECT
count( * ) AS AGGREGATE 
FROM
`report_ifind`
INNER JOIN `report_descriptions` ON `report_ifind`.`seq` = 
`report_descriptions`.`report_seq` 
AND `description` IS NOT NULL 
WHERE
EXISTS (
SELECT
1 
FROM
`report_types` 
WHERE
report_ifind.seq = report_types.report_seq 
AND `type_code` NOT IN ( '002', '001001', '001002', '001003', '099001002', 
'009001001', '003001', '003002', '003003', '004002' ) 
) 
AND `isvalid` = 1 
AND `report_ifind`.`publish_time` >= '2017-06-24'
```

There is three table in this query：

```
report_ifind
report_descriptions
report_types
```

The index of those table:

```
**report_ifind**:
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `idx_seq` (`seq`),
KEY `idx_research_id` (`researcher_id`),
KEY `idx_org_id` (`org_id`),
KEY `idx_publish_time` (`publish_time`) USING BTREE,
KEY `idx_sql_publish_time` (`publish_time`,`seq`) USING BTREE

**report_descriptions**:
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `idx_report_seq` (`report_seq`)

**report_types**:
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `idx_report_seq` (`report_seq`),
KEY `idx_type_code` (`type_code`)
```

I know something is bad:

1、 " desctiption is not null " is slow

2、 " WHERE EXIST () " is slow

3、 " SELECT COUNT(*) " is slow

Question is : How to improve it?

The EXPLAIN output:
[explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1v9w9.png)

Comment: You can add another indexes to 'report_ifind.description' and 'report_types.isvalid' columns  this may help full

Comment: its hard to add index to 'description'. 

And i think add index to 'isvalid' is not helpful cause it has only two value.

Comment: other than those two columns you have indexed all. so no idea for me :)

Comment: Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MySQL 5.6 or later,you should use IN instead of EXISTS, if possible.  In this case:

```
... WHERE report_ifind.seq IN (
          SELECT report_seq FROM report_types 
          WHERE type_code NOT IN ('002', '001001', '001002', '001003', '099001002', 
                                  '009001001', '003001', '003002', '003003', '004002' ) 
    ) ...
```

Whether this will benefit you is impossible to say without knowing the selectivity of your WHERE conditions.  Generally, to recommend how to improve a query, one will need to see the current query plan (i.e., EXPLAIN output.)

Comment: Thanks. I add the query plan in the end of question.

Answer (score 0):

3、 " SELECT COUNT(*) " is slow

Try counting just `id` column (`COUNT(report_ifind.id)`) instead of counting all columns from table.

Comment: Why would you expect this to have a meaningful impact on the query time?  Wouldn't the RDMBS still have to count the same number of records?

Comment: it doesn't work.    
The key to slow is the full table scan,